# how can we neatly shift data from a folder to a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, h5py

I want to convert images in folder c:\user\img , which are labelled as 1.png,2.png, .....100.png to be saved in .h5 file in python.

Can some tell me a neat way to do this. I have searched many posts but they are very indirect or some uses a np.array images to store in .h5

thanks

Comment: I think I might understand your misconception. HDF5 essentially stores matrices (of for example integers, doubles, or something else). In your case this means you would have to read the data from your PNGs (e.g. using `matplotlib`) to a NumPy array. This you can then easily store in the HDF5 file.

Comment: If I use matplotlib: 
from matplotlib.image import imread
img=imread('cm.png')

now the shape of img.shape = (158,209,3)
where as in real it is a (65,35) grayscale image.....
which format i can save it to have the dims i want

Comment: That the last dimension is `3` is not surprising. Matplotlib will always read RGB-values. If you are confident the input is just grayscale all three should be identical and you can just pick one (discarding the two others), e.g.: `img = img[:,:,0]`. The difference in the other dimensions is weird. Are you sure that you are treating the same image? Can you edit your questing into a minimal working example?

Comment: Yes i can take the image's 1 dimension but there is an extra boxed area showing with the image so the image size is 158x209 but the actual image is inside this dimension with dims=65x35> I think it has to do with my saving procedure which is not right. Thank you for the help @TomdeGeus